# Regular expression with carriage return

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to extra the value which follows the word 'Total' but I'm not sure how to handle the carriage return which means i'm searching over 2 separate lines. does anyone know the best way to approach this ?

```
Taxes&Charges↵
↵
£ 35.97↵
↵
Total↵
£ 198.98↵
↵
£ 35.97↵
↵
↵
Total↵
£ 333.98
```

Comment: Which flavor of regex are you using?

Comment: This totally depends on how you're getting your text into the application -- one line at a time or the whole file in a string value, for instance. Also, it depends on the language you're using -- while most regex implementations have more or less the same options to deal with multiple lines, the ways to invoke them are different.

Comment: What do you mean by "to extra the value"?

Comment: [When asking regex questions, always add tag for the specific programming language or tool (e.g., Perl, Python, or Java; vi, emacs, or ɢɴᴜ grep; etc.) you are using.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

Answer (score 28):

In regex you should use the `\r` to catch the carriage return and `\r\n` to catch the line breaks

Answer (score 7):

You should use regex option *dot matches newline* (if supported).

E.g. in `.NET` you could use [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) for this. It specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (`.`) so it matches every character (instead of every character except `\n`).

The next expression:

```
Regex ex = new Regex(@"(?<=Total\r\n)£\s?[\d.]+", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

will match `£ 198.98` and `£ 333.98` values from your test example.

Answer (score 2):

Add `s` modifier to your regex. `s` means treat string as single line. Why don't you remove carriage return with `str_replace` first? Oops, no PHP tag.

Answer (score 2):

If you add s, to signify the single line, you can then (for example if windows) use

`^Total\r\n£([ 0-9.]+)\r\n"`  to extract the total values.

(not tested, the brackets should ensure it appears as a group value)