# Regex to match any characters after carriage returns and give a single delimited string

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to find all the words between two words using Java. These words are on new lines. See my sample text below :

**Sample text:**

```
this is
an example
for the problem(s)
I
am having
while
working on
the issue-101
```

I need all the words *[including special characters]* after the word **example** and delimited by some character, lets say pipe |

**Expected output:**

```
for the problem(s)|I|am having|while|working on|the issue-101
```

**I tried with the below RegEx:**

```
(?<=example\r\n)\s?\w+
```

**which gives me only:**

```
for
```

I know the above regex is not complete but I expected it to give me atleast all the words first then think about adding the delimiter.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated. Found one question [Regular expression with carriage return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532920/regular-expression-with-carriage-return)
which is more or less similar to my question and still doesnt help me completely.

Comment: and you need to use regex? because this is simpel to do in plain java

Comment: @chillworld yes, I need to use regex because my applciation consumes lot of regexes and the patterns vary too. So I have parameterized all the regex strings.

Comment: with pure regex I can't help you further (maybe take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638060/replace-a-single-character-within-a-match-via-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to combine 2 replacements in single `String#replaceAll` call:

```
String repl = data.replaceAll("(?s)(.*?example\\s*)|[\r\n]+", "|");
//=> |for the problem(s)|I|am having|while|working on|the issue-101
```

- Only caveat is that it will have a starting pipe character in the output.
- `(?s)` is for DOTALL to make dot match newlines also.

Comment: Your answer best suits my needs. But I was just wondering if there is any built-in way to replace the pipe in regex itself. Instead of using replaceAll function of Java. I am new to RegEx, so pardon me if I am being stupid in asking this :)

Comment: This is the closest you can get without any loop or multiple `replaceAll` calls. Pipe character has to be part of replacement string only.

Answer (score 1):

First replace all newlines with pipes, then remove the text up to the delimiter:

```
String target = input.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", "|").replaceAll("^.*?example\\|", "");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to achieve this using single regex and the output available to me in a single captured group. This is because my applciation consumes lot of regexes and the patterns vary too. So I have parameterized all the regex strings. Sorry for not including this limitation in question.

Comment: @Bohemian compilation error -- *Syntax error on tokens, ( expected instead* - What needs to be changed???

Comment: A double quote needs to be added.  String target = input.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", "|").replaceAll("^.*?example", "");